# If product of two sets $A\times B$ is closed, are $A$ and $B$ closed?

Tags: general-topology

If $A\times B$ is closed in $X\times Y$, then are $A$ and $B$ closed in $X$ and $Y$ respectively?

Comment: I guess $X\times Y$ with product Topology ?

Comment: What is the reason of -2(in voting)? There are many more elementary question with much more upvotes.

Comment: @vesszabo The difficulty of a question is inversely proportional to the number of votes is receives.

Answer (score 6):

We assume $A,B$ to be non-empty. Let $b\in B$. Show that the restriction $p_X^b:=p_X|_{X\times\{b\}}:X\times\{b\}\to X$ of the projection $p_X$ onto $X$ is a homeomorphism. Now, $A=p_X^b[(A\times B)\cap(X\times\{b\})]$ and $(A\times B)\cap (X\times\{b\})$ is closed in the subspace $X\times\{b\}$

Similarly, the restriction of $p_Y$ to $\{a\}\times Y,\ a\in A$ is a homeomorphism. It follows that $B$ is closed.

Alternatively, you could prove the stronger result $\overline{A\times B}=\overline A\times\overline B$ (this is even true for an infinite product!) and use this to obtain the solution.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Suppose that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in $X$, and let $b$ be any point of $B$. Let $p=\langle x,b\rangle$, and show that $p\in\operatorname{cl}_{X\times Y}(A\times B)$. Conclude that $p\in A\times B$ and hence that $x\in A$.

**Added:** Note that as Henno points out in the comments, the result is false if $A$ or $B$ is allowed to be empty: $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$ is closed for all $A$, whether or not $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Your argument also shows that we need both $A$ and $B$ to be non-empty, otherwise one empty factor and one non-closed one in the other does yield a closed (namely empty) product.