# Is product of two closed sets closed?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

If $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$,

does it follow that $A \times B$ is closed in $X \times Y$ ?

Comment: You think it that this statement is true or false? That’s bold!

Comment: I think we did have the same question some time ago

Comment: @DominicMichaelis It's the opposite direction.

Comment: @VedranŠego So it’s no duplicate, indeed. Yet the answer given by StefanH. to the linked question answers this question, too.

Comment: @VedranŠego oh right didn't read careful enough

Comment: It seems that some of the comments were deleted. So that the comments make sense, the linked question mentioned there is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468437/product-of-two-sets-is-closed).

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: And about the reverse, if the product is closed so each one is closed? Thank you so much

Comment: @Quiet_waters You can see this post among the linked questions: [If product of two sets $A\times B$ is closed, are $A$ and $B$ closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468437)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you!

Comment: Here is a pretty neat proof that works for both finite and infinite product spaces (and hence implies the result OP asked for): https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Closed_Sets_is_Closed

Answer (score 47):

$A$ is closed in $X$, so $A^c$ is open, likewise for $B$ in $Y$.

Moreover, $A^c \times Y$ and $X \times B^c$ are both open in $X \times Y$.

Thus $$(A \times B)^c = (A^c \times Y) \cup (X \times B^c)  $$ is open. Hence $A \times B$ is closed.

Comment: why did you not include $A^C\times B^C$?

Comment: @Killaspe Because $A^C\times B^C \subseteq A^C\times Y$ or also $A^C\times B^C\subseteq X\times B^C$.

Answer (score 11):

Let $\pi_i$ denote the projection on $i$-th coordinate

Product topology: $X×B^c = π_2^{-1}(B^c)$ is open in $X×Y$, and $A^c×Y = π_1^{-1}(A^c)$ is open in $X×Y$. And $(A×B)^c = ?$

Comment: maybe say somewhere that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the projections to the first ( to the second) component

Comment: Why do $A$ and $B$ need to be non-empty?

Comment: @StefanSmith I don’t know. Maybe you don’t. I probably was thinking about the converse direction, since it was linked.

Answer (score 6):

Recall that a subset $A$ of a topological space is closed iff limit of every convergent [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) with terms in $A$ also belongs to $A$.

In metric spaces (and, more generally, in [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space)) nets can be replaced by sequences in the above characterization. (So if this context is sufficient for you, the argument below works just the same - and can be followed without any knowledge about nets.)

Let $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ be closed subsets of topological spaces $X$, $Y$, respectively.

- Let us assume that a net $(a_d,b_d)_{d\in D}$ converges to $(a,b)$ in $X\times Y$ and $(a_d,b_d)\in A\times B$.
- This implies that $a_d\to a$ in $X$, and $b_d\to b$ in $Y$. (For example, using continuity of the projections. If $p_1 \colon X\times Y \to X$ denotes the projection $p_1(x,y)=x$, then we get $p_1(a_d,b_d)\to p_1(a,b)$ which is exactly $a_d\to a$.)
- From this we get $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, i.e., $(a,b)\in A\times B$. (Since both $A$, $B$ are closed.)

Since this shows that $A\times B$ is closed under limits of nets, the above characterization gives us closedness of $A\times B$.

Answer (score 0):

If we can find an open neighborhood $U_x \subset {(A \times B)}^c$ given any arbitrary $x \in {(A \times B)}^c$ this would imply that ${(A \times B)}^c$ is open and thus $(A \times B)$ would be closed.

Given $x \in (A \times B), \; where \; x=(x_1,y_1) \; s.t. \; x_1 \in X \; and \; y_1 \in Y.$ Then $x_1 \in X-A$ which is open and $y_1 \in Y-B$ which is also open. Therefore $\exists \; \; {U_x}_1 \in X-A \; and \; {U_y}_1 \in Y-B,$ open neighborhoods about $x_1$ and $y_1$ respectively.

${U_x}_1 \times {U_y}_1$ is an open set in $X \times Y \; and \; {U_x}_1 \times {U_y}_1$ is an open neighborhood of our arbitrary point i $x \in {(A \times B)}^c.$ Therefore, ${(A \times B)}^c$ is open implying that $(A \times B)$ is closed.

Comment: Please spend some time learning $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference so that everyone can easily understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is closed in $X$, so $A^c$ is open, likewise for $B$ in $Y$.

Moreover, $A^c\times Y$ and $X\times B^c$ are both open in $X\times Y$.

Thus $(A\times B)^c=(A^c\times Y)\cup(X\times B^c)$ is open. Hence $A\times B$ is closed.

Answer (score -1):

Given $A$ and $B$ are closed sets, let $(x,y)$ be a limit point of $A \times B$. Then there exists a sequence $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ in $A \times B$ such that $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ converges to $(x, y)$.

Since $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ is a sequence in $A \times B$, $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $A$ and $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence in $B$.

Also, since $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ converges to $(x, y)$, $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ and $\{y_n\}$ converges to $y$.

We obtain a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ converging to $x$. This implies that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ and hence it is in the closure of $A$. Since $A$ is closed, $A$ equals it closure, i.e. $x$ is in $A$.

Similarly, we can prove $y$ is in $B$.

Therefore, $(x, y)$ is in $A \times B$, i.e. $A \times B$ contains all its limit points.

Hence $A \times B$ is closed.