# Prove that a closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

Prove that a closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a closed set.

**My trial:**

Define the closed rectangle  by: $A=\{a_{1} \leq x_{1} \leq b_{1},a_{2} \leq x_{2} \leq b_{2}, ...,a_{n} \leq x_{n} \leq b_{n} \}$

A closed set is defined as a set that contains all its cluster points.

Distinguish between 2 cases:

**Case1: $x \in A$.**

Then there exist an interval $[a,b]$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$ by the definition of a closed rectangle and then $A \cap [a,b]$\ $\{x\} \neq \phi$.

Is this justification correct?

**Case2:$x \notin A.$**

Then distinguish between 2 cases:

**Case a:**

$\inf|| x - A|| = 0$

Then in this case $x$ is a cluster point of A **(either A is closed or open it does not matter)** then there exist a sequence $c_{k} \in A$ such that $c_{k} \rightarrow x$ as $k \rightarrow \infty.$ But since $c_{k} \in A$ then $a_{i} \leq c_{k} \leq b_{i}.$ Then by squeeze theorem and since  $a_{i}$ & $b_{i}$ are constants we have $a_{i} \leq x  \leq b_{i}.$ which means that $x \in A$ which is a contradiction to our assumption..... but I do not know what should I conclude then? ...... may be this case can not exist i.e. the infimum can not be equal zero?

**Case b:**

$\inf||x - A|| \neq 0 $

Then put $ a = \inf||x - A|| ,$ then the interval $[x - a, x + a]$ does not contain other points of $A$ and hence $x$ is not a cluster point of $A$ in this case..... is my argument correct in this case?

Could anyone help me filling the gaps in my proof please?

**EDIT 1:**

**Case1: $x \in A$.**

Then there exist $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $a_{i} \leq x_{i} \leq b_{i}$ by the definition of a closed rectangle and then $A \cap [a_{i},b_{i}]$\ $\{x_{i}\} \neq \phi  \forall  i$.

And hence $x_{i}$ is a cluster point of $A$ $\forall i$ and $x \in A$ ...... is my new edit correct?

**EDIT 2:**

**Case b:**

The following case should be deleted because it is not a cluster point.

$\inf||x - A|| \neq 0 $

Then put $ a = \inf||x - A|| ,$ then the interval $[x - a, x + a]$ does not contain other points of $A$ and hence $x$ is not a cluster point of $A$ in this case..... is my argument correct in this case?

Comment: Don't you need only the case that $x$ is a cluster point?

Comment: $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:a_1\leq x_1\leq b_1,...,a_n\leq x_n\leq b_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and thus $A\cap [a,b]=\emptyset$ ...and $a\leq x\leq b$ for $x\in A$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ makes no sense

Comment: case 1.  False when a = b and x cannot be in an interval when n > 1.

Comment: I could not understand your comment @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: So could you please provide me with a rigorous answer @PeterMelech

Comment: So could you please provide me with a rigorous answer @WilliamElliot

Comment: why I need only the case $x$ is a cluster point @HagenvonEitzen ?

Comment: @PeterMelech so is this the only mistake I have in my solution?

Comment: I have edited my solution ..... could you check it please?@PeterMelech

Comment: I have edited my solution ..... could you check it please? ....... I will also remove the case when $x \notin A$ and $ \inf \neq 0$ @HagenvonEitzen ....... I see that it is irrelevant as you said above

Comment: What does "Then there exist an interval [a,b] such that a≤x≤b" mean?  $x$ is n-tuple point in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$ doesn't have an order.  Are you saying $a,b$ are n-tuple points in $\mathbb R^n$ and $a \le x \le b$ is shorthand for $a_i \le x \le b_i$?  If so what is the point?  the rectangle is that? Or do you mean $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $a\le x\le b$ is shorthand for $a\le x_i \le b$.  If so, how do you know.  ANd any way... what's the point.  What does this case show?

Comment: I have just edited this case at the end of my post @fleablood

Comment: I don't understand your Edit 1: at all.  To begin with there isn't one $i$.  That's true for all $i$. Second, $[a_i,b_i]\subset \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\cap \mathbb R^n = \emptyset$ so so $A\cap[a_i,b_i]=\emptyset$ and thirdly, what does *any* of that have to do with cluster points, and fourthly ao what if all points in A are cluster points (which they aren't; the border points are not cluster points)?  that's that's neither required nor sufficient to be closed.

Comment: You only need one case.  1: $x$ is a cluster point of $A\implies$ $x \in A$.  That's the *only* thing that is relevant.  If $x$ is not a cluster point of $A$ it does not matter if $x$ in $A$ or not.  If $x$ is in $A$ it does not matter if it is or is not a cluster point.  If 2: $x\not \in A\implies x \not \in A$ is another case but it is completely equivalent (contrapositive) to $1$ so you only have to choose one or the other to prove.  (Advice: prove 1.

Comment: your comments are so valuable :) thank you ........ that was exactly what I am looking for ...... correction to my solution ........ could you please write an explicit answer for me so that I can accept an answer for this question?@fleablood

Comment: @fleablood ..... do you mean that I need not edit case 1 and it was written correctly or what shall I do to correct it?

Comment: why $\mathbb{R} \cap \mathbb{R^n} = \emptyset $? does not $(x, 0 ,0 .....,0)$ n-tuple belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: for your very first comment ..... so what is the correct way to  write case 1?@fleablood  I got confused...... actually this case is saying that the set A contains all the cluster points of A that lies inside A.

Comment: For your second comment so how can I correct this case ? or what shall I do? @fleablood

Comment: I think that for your last comment the conclusion of the implication is incorrect @fleablood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot comment yet so I must post in answer. Sorry about that.

Well any $[a_i,b_i]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Now the Cartesian product $A \times B$ of two closed set $A$ (closed in $X$) and B (closed in $Y$) is closed in $X \times Y$ (see [Is product of two closed sets closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479777/is-product-of-two-closed-sets-closed)). So then your rectangle is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the Cartesian product of $n$ closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'd almost call this an answer, except that it's just a little too topological for the given definition of closed.

Comment: @TheoBendit yes I agree. That's why I wanted to make a comment below the post instead of posting it as answer since the author seems to want a proof via cluster points. But I did not have enough reputation. Thanks to the upvote, I can now comment.

Comment: @Plussoyeur Another more ;)

Comment: thank you for your solution but I need a correction to my solution not a new solution

Answer (score 2):

I'll try though I prefer Plussoyeur's answer. Consider $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ so that for every neighborhood $U\in \mathcal{U}(x)$, ( the system of neighborhoods) You have
$$U\cap A\neq\emptyset.$$
(So $x$ is an  clusterpoint of $A$.) Call $$P_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ \cdot\\\cdot\\x_i\\\cdot\\x_n\end{pmatrix}\mapsto x_i$$
the projection on the $i$'th component and for each $U\in\mathcal{U}(x)$ define $U_i=P_i(U)$ for $i=1,...,n$. Now by the product-topology the projections are open and thus $U_i$ is a neighborhood of $x_i$ that satisfies
$$U_i\cap[a_i,b_i]\neq\emptyset$$
for $i=1,...,n$. Thus $x_i\in[a_i,b_i]$ for $i=1,...,n$ and so $x\in A$.

Comment: thank you for your solution but I need a correction to my solution not a new solution